# C++ based rule engine

Tags: c++

i am looking for a good c++ rule engine. can you please let me know if there there any XML based rule engine for C++

Comment: what is a "rule engine"?

Comment: @reko_t http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1596073/what-is-rule-engine

Comment: @reko_t: Rule Engine is basically a controller that parses rules from a rules database and applies it on a certain transaction/data/input.

Comment: Please check [here](http://www.flexrule.com/archives/business-rule-engine-bre/) to have an explanation of what is a rule engine.

Answer (score 6):

Check [CLIPS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CLIPS) (developed originally by NASA) Its a rules engine written in C. It is under continuous development for many years. However, the rules are defined in LISP like rule defintion language.

Its hosted on sourceforge  http://clipsrules.sourceforge.net/

Answer (score 1):

I guess the answer to "what is a rule engine" is there : [What can Rules Engines accomplish?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1596073/what-is-rule-engine)

But that's a too broad definition. In fact a "rule engine" should be totally dependant on your domain. The engine will provide settings (XML based or anything else suitable for the task) and then apply the rules.

So look for domain-specific engines and you'll certainly find something useful.

Answer (score 0):

ILog Rules(IBM) is writen in C++.